# SQLAlchemy: How to acess class properties when using column_property?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables\classes in my database:Movies,Pictures and MediaFolders,
When I add a mediafolder, python scans the given path and adds pictures and movies in that path to the database.

I wish to have the ability to tell how many Pictures\Movies I have in a given MediaFolder so I added a column_property of 'movie_count' and 'picture_count'
to my class. However this doesn't seem to work, as evident by the SQL output where 'path_to_dir' is converted to 'no name'

I'll appreciate it if someone would point out what am I doing wrong.

```
class MediaFolder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MediaFolder'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    path_to_dir = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    is_picture = Column(Boolean)
    is_video = Column(Boolean)

    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

    last_scan = Column(DateTime)

    movie_count = column_property(
        select([func.count(Movie.id)]).where(Movie.path_to_file.like('{}%'.format(path_to_dir)).correlate_except(Movie)
    ))

    picture_count = column_property(
        select([func.count(Picture.id)]).where(Picture.path_to_file.like('{}%'.format(path_to_dir))).correlate_except(
            Picture)
    )
```

The SQL echo output is as follows:

```
2017-03-30 18:53:49,671 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT (SELECT count("Movie".id) AS count_1 
FROM "Movie" 
WHERE "Movie".path_to_file LIKE ?) AS anon_1, (SELECT count("Picture".id) AS count_2 
FROM "Picture" 
WHERE "Picture".path_to_file LIKE ?) AS anon_2, "MediaFolder".id AS "MediaFolder_id", "MediaFolder".name AS "MediaFolder_name", "MediaFolder".path_to_dir AS "MediaFolder_path_to_dir", "MediaFolder".is_picture AS "MediaFolder_is_picture", "MediaFolder".is_video AS "MediaFolder_is_video", "MediaFolder".created_at AS "MediaFolder_created_at", "MediaFolder".updated_at AS "MediaFolder_updated_at", "MediaFolder".last_scan AS "MediaFolder_last_scan" 
FROM "MediaFolder" 
WHERE "MediaFolder".id = ?
2017-03-30 18:53:49,672 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('(no name)%', '(no name)%', 1)
```

**EDIT**

Movie model:

```
class Movie(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Movie'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        path_to_file = Column(String)
```

Picture Model:

```
class Picture(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Picture'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        path_to_file = Column(String)
```

As to the code that invokes movie_count and picture_count: They are both `column_property` which means they are loaded whenever the model is loaded for example:
`a = Session.query(MediaFolder).filter(MediaFolder.id == 1).one()` one should be able to do `a.movie_count` and get the movie count.
The SQL echo output above is what I get when I try to load a MediaFolder exactly in this way.

**PS**
I have other `column_property` that don't rely on the `like` keyword and they work perfectly fine.

For example this is a column property in the Actor model which counts the amount of pictures a certain actor has:

```
 picture_count = column_property(
        select([func.count(picture_actors.c.actor_id)]).where(picture_actors.c.actor_id == id).correlate_except(
            picture_actors)
    )
```

Where `picture_actors` is a relation table (And not a model) and defined as follows:

```
picture_actors = Table('Picture_Actor', Base.metadata,
                       Column('picture_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Picture.id'), index=True),
                       Column('actor_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Actor.id'), index=True),
                       )
```

Comment: please add also your models for `Picture` and `Movie`, and the code in which you invoke `movie_count`/`picture_count`

Comment: @knitti I've edited the question to include this information.

Comment: At the moment I'm not entirely sure what exactly the problem is... There seems nothing wrong with your expression in itself, perhaps there's something wonky with the "like" expression? or that for that specific dialect? Would you try `.match()` instead of `like()` perhaps?

Comment: @knitti match() uses a database-specific MATCH or CONTAINS function; its behavior will vary by backend and is not available on some backends such as SQLite. (I'm using SQLite)